# how do oracle deal with batch insert?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Now I am using JDBC executeBatch function to insert multi rows into a table. The java code likes below:

````
 ```
 String sql = "insert into t values (?, ?, ?)";
 preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     preparedStatement.setInt(1, i);
     preparedStatement.setString(2, "jack"+i);
     preparedStatement.setString(3, "tom"+i);
     preparedStatement.addBatch();  
     if ((i+1)%10==0) {
         preparedStatement.executeBatch();  
     }
 }
 ```
````

It faster enough than executeUpdate rows one by one. I know in MySql the sql could be rewrite to "Insert into t values(xx,xx,xx), (xx,xx,xx)...". The above code only need to execute 10 times in Mysql.
But there is not such sql syntax in Oracle. What makes oracle so fast? And I also find there is only 10 sqlbinds in dba_audit_trail. Where is tom0 ~ tom8 ?

```
  #1(1):9 #2(5):jack9 #3(5):tom9
  #1(2):19 #2(6):jack19 #3(6):tom19
  #1(2):29 #2(6):jack29 #3(6):tom29
  #1(2):39 #2(6):jack39 #3(6):tom39
  #1(2):49 #2(6):jack49 #3(6):tom49
  #1(2):59 #2(6):jack59 #3(6):tom59
  #1(2):69 #2(6):jack69 #3(6):tom69
  #1(2):79 #2(6):jack79 #3(6):tom79
  #1(2):89 #2(6):jack89 #3(6):tom89
  #1(2):99 #2(6):jack99 #3(6):tom99
```

Comment: According to the documentation of the JDBC driver batching is supported (at least from the JDBC perspective). So there is probably some optimization being done on that level. Probably sending 1 query with mutliple bindings instead of multiple queries.

Comment: You should execute to statement after the loop has finished. If `(i+1)%10 != 0` then the batch contains un-executed values after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database supports array binds. That is it allows clients to bind an array of values to each of the parameters in a SQL. Oracle Database JDBC uses array binds to execute batch execution when possible. Note that it isn't always possible. In the example code you show it would be possible so the Oracle Database JDBC Driver would execute one round trip for each call to `executeBatch`. That round trip would execute the `INSERT` with a ten element array bound to each of the three parameters.

For the driver to use array binds the SQL must be identical, and the elements of each separate array must be the same type. The elements of different arrays can be of different types, but for a given array (parameter) all the bound values must be the same type. This frequently shows up when mixing `DATE` with `TIMESTAMP` values for one parameter. Every time the type changes requires an additional round trip.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle, It use FORALL.

```
create or replace procedure nobatch is
begin
  for x in (select * from t)
  loop
    insert into t1 (id, name1, name2, name3, name4)
    values (x.id, x.name1, x.name2, x.name3, x.name4);
  end loop;
  commit;
end nobatch;
/
```

```
create or replace procedure usebatch (p_array_size in pls_integer)
is
  type array is table of t%rowtype;
  l_data array;
  cursor c is select * from t;
begin
  open c;
  loop
    fetch c bulk collect into l_data limit p_array_size;
    forall i in 1..l_data.count insert into t1 values l_data(i);
    exit when c%notfound;
  end loop;
  commit;
  close c;
end usebatch;
/
```

```
SQL> exec nobatch;  
Elapsed: 00:00:32.92

SQL> exec usebatch(50);
Elapsed: 00:00:00.77

SQL> exec usebatch(100);
Elapsed: 00:00:00.47

SQL> exec usebatch(1000);
Elapsed: 00:00:00.19

SQL> exec usebatch(100000);
Elapsed: 00:00:00.26
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).